# Cannot get the strings into a single line getting body text using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, text, beautifulsoup

I have bunch of xml files and I am trying to exctract from those files by using beautifulsoup. Here is my code:

```
text = """
<B510>
<B511><PDAT>G03B 2742</PDAT></B511>
<B512><PDAT>G03B 2758</PDAT></B512>
<B512><PDAT>G03B 2762</PDAT></B512>
<B516><PDAT>7</PDAT></B516>
</B510>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

### Classification info
class_info = soup.find_all("b510")
class_info = ", ".join([x.text.strip() for x in class_info])
```

This is what I get:

```
G03B 2742
G03B 2758
G03B 2762
7
```

Why I cannot get the text into a sinle line?

Comment: `[x.text.strip() for x in int_classes]` int_classes is undefined at this point.  Can this code even run?  Please post an actual working example.

Comment: I fixed  the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `<PDAT>` should be enough:

```
[i.text for i in soup.find('b510').find_all("pdat")]
```

**output**:

```
['G03B 2742', 'G03B 2758', 'G03B 2762', '7']
```

Comment: The problem is that actual data is more complex, I should use  b510 somehow

Comment: Check simple modification.